# Writing Parquet file in Apache Crunch

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2, parquet, apache-crunch

I am new in apache crunch and looking for reading and writing Parquet file in apache crunch.
I followed the documentation and API but did not get straight approach/method for doing the same.

```
PCollection<String> pipeLine = MemPipeline.collectionOf("Pineapple", "Banana", "Orange");

PCollection<Integer> b = pipeLine.parallelDo(new DoFn<String, Integer>() {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   public void process(String input, Emitter<Integer> emitter) {
        emitter.emit(input.length());
    }
  }, ints());

  b.write(new AvroParquetFileTarget("D:\\Tutorials\\CCP_WorkSpace\\Crunch\\resources\\output"));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with approaches you tried and links of documentation you followed. Also, paste the code which did not work. :)

Comment: `PCollection<String> pipeLine = MemPipeline.collectionOf("Pineapple", "Banana", "Orange");

  PCollection<Integer> b = pipeLine.parallelDo(new DoFn<String, Integer>() {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   public void process(String input, Emitter<Integer> emitter) {
    emitter.emit(input.length());
   }
  }, ints());

  b.write(new AvroParquetFileTarget("D:\\Tutorials\\WorkSpace\\Crunch\\resources\\output"));
 }
`

Comment: Thanks @SagarKulkarni for you response, above is the code which am trying.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code with proper indentations. :)

Comment: @SagarKulkarni I've added the code snippet in question box, sorry for inconvenience caused :)

Comment: No problem. :) Just go through the documentation for "How to ask a question on stack overflow" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question next time.

Answer (score 1):

if you have an avro schema and a compiled class from that avro which contains the same structure of your parquet data, you can read it in the following way

```
AvroParquetFileSource<MyClassCompiled> avroParquetFileSource = 
new AvroParquetFileSource<MyClassCompiled>(
                    new Path(input), Avros.records(MyClassCompiled.class)
);
```

and write parquet like this

```
Target parquetFileTarget = new AvroParquetFileTarget(outputPath);
mypcollection.write(avroParquetFileSource);
```